# How to replace all the sentence with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Iam trying to make the code to remove the extra space, here is my code

```
Sub ColourChange()
       For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
                LArray = Split(sentence, " ")
                var = ""
                For Each Text In LArray
                    If Text <> "" Then
                        var = var + " " + Text
                    End If
                Next
        Next
End Sub
```

But I try to replace the current sentence with the new sentence (var) which has already remove the extra space but it can't be done :( anyone know how to replace the whole sentence ?

Comment: Where is the extra space? At the beginning, somewhere in the middle, the end? Did you want to replace all the spaces?

Comment: The `Trim$()` function doesnt do what you want?

Comment: `var = Trim$(var + " " + Text)`

Comment: Yeah but how to replace the sentence to the new sentence which is var here ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how to replace existing sentences with new ones.

```
Private Sub ColourChange()

    Dim OldSen As String, NewSen As String
    Dim SenRng As Range

    For Each SenRng In ActiveDocument.Sentences
        OldSen = SenRng.Text
        NewSen = "(((" & OldSen & ")))"
        SenRng.Text = NewSen
    Next SenRng
End Sub
```

Please observe that `Sentence` is a range, and a member of the `Sentences` collection.

I don't understand what you wish to do with the spaces, but if your intention is to remove extra blanks you might consider using the replace function, like,
`NewSen = Replace(OldSen, "  ", " ")`